Issues with requests to rest API when manual triggered on an angular app
I have an Angular application which is empty, just an app component with nothing fancy in it.
I have a function to run a GET request to a rest API. The request is just for testing purpose, so it does nothing and return some mock data. I use HttpClient of Angular to make that request.
In the lifecycle ngOnInit I run that function and it works fine.
In the page there is a button that run the same function. When I use that button, I have an error :
Status : 0
Error : TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at http://localhost:55651/polyfills.js:1255:30
    at proto.<computed> (http://localhost:55651/polyfills.js:782:16)
    at _FetchBackend.<anonymous> (http://localhost:55651/@fs/C:/Users/morgan/issue/.angular/cache/17.3.2/vite/deps/chunk-EONTFRYP.js?v=baac2411:1128:35)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:55651/@fs/C:/Users/morgan/issue/.angular/cache/17.3.2/vite/deps/chunk-KJBDP7EP.js?v=baac2411:49:61
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (http://localhost:55651/polyfills.js:1185:21)
    at __async (http://localhost:55651/@fs/C:/Users/morgan/issue/.angular/cache/17.3.2/vite/deps/chunk-KJBDP7EP.js?v=baac2411:33:10)
    at _FetchBackend.doRequest (http://localhost:55651/@fs/C:/Users/morgan/issue/.angular/cache/17.3.2/vite/deps/chunk-EONTFRYP.js?v=baac2411:1124:12)
    at Observable2._subscribe (http://localhost:55651/@fs/C:/Users/morgan/issue/.angular/cache/17.3.2/vite/deps/chunk-EONTFRYP.js?v=baac2411:1117:12)
    at Observable2._trySubscribe (http://localhost:55651/@fs/C:/Users/morgan/issue/.angular/cache/17.3.2/vite/deps/chunk-KJBDP7EP.js?v=baac2411:1131:19)

If I run the same GET request from a shell, I do not have any problem.
My nginx access.log show those lines :
MY-IP - - [07/Apr/2024:14:12:58 +0000] "GET /tmpTest HTTP/1.1" 200 26 "-" "node"
My-IP - - [07/Apr/2024:14:13:00 +0000] "GET /tmpTest HTTP/1.1" 200 26 "http://localhost:55651/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/108.0.0.0"

So the first time, if I understand correctly, the request is made by node, and the second time with my browser (which makes sense). I'm unsure if it's crucial, but I'm clueless about where to look.
Notice that when the Rest Api (which is made with Flask) is served locally, I do not have the issue. But it occurs when it's on a server (with nginx and gunicorn).
I made a stackblitz but when I run the app with it, I got the error in both cases (with ngOnInit and with the button) : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-r5psb2?file=src%2Fmain.ts
I know that its a newbie question, and I'm sorry for that but I'm completely stuck...

It happens when your HTTP request's headers claim that the content is gzip encoded, but it isn't. If you do a regular request in browser and inspect the request, you will see  the header:
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection:     keep-alive
Host:34.163.40.91:5000
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:  1


Thanks. This is my headers : `GET /tmpTest HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/plain, /
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 34.163.40.91:5000
Origin: http://localhost:55651
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:55651/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/108.0.0.0`
What do you suggest I do ?

@Morgan Disable compression on server in nginx.

I turned to set  gzip to off but it didn't did the trick. At the same time, I saw in the Network tab of the Devtools that the status of my error was CORS error. It was not display in the console. I enabled cross origines in my Flask app and it seams to do the trick... While I do not realy understand why, I will make some research before claiming victory. Making something that work is great, understand why is better ^^...
